# How and where is best to store program and user settings and user generated data in a tkinter application?

Tags: python, tkinter, software-distribution

Suppose you have gone through the process of producing a gui application using tkinter. The project is stored on github or in a directory online where the user can download said application. How can I deal with the general "housekeeping" of deploying said app? I'm thinking in terms of "hands-off" usability, much like when a user might download a program like firefox and it just creates all of the requisite files and folders and desktop shortcuts.

1. How do you deal with installation of dependencies? For instance, a script that checks for installed packages or even automatically creates a virtual environment before installing them. How could it be set so that it doesn't bother checking after the initial installation?
2. Where do you store generic configuration settings for the program? How can you check for them on startup?
3. Where do you store configuration settings specific to the user? How can you check for them on startup?
4. Let's say the program stores user generated data in a database, most conveniently a sqlite db. Where would this most appropriately be stored? I'm thinking I could create a whole other separate part of my program to switch, create, delete, backup database files.

Are these considerations a separate discipline of programming and if so, what is it called and where can I learn about it?

I'd be grateful for answers which consider the separate nuances of Windows/Mac/GNU-Linux.

Answer (score 2):

## Storage

You can easily make a hidden directory on any platform as shown below

You can store all your program info, settings.ini, sqlite.db and all of the stuff here. The generic stuff can be stored here as well.

## Windows

For Windows, I recommend using APPDATA/Roaming, because, well, because of the name.

You can easily use Path to get the path name and can easily implement it like this:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import os
change_dir_to = os.chdir(f'{Path.home()}/AppData/Roaming')
try:
    os.mkdir("Your App Name")
except:
    pass
changed_dir_to = os.chdir("Your App Name")
```

You can then use this in your application easily. There are obivious better ways to implement this, but this is the easiest way I could think of. See [this](https://github.com/newtoallofthis123/leaf/blob/main/leaf.py) for a good reference for this type of implementation in windows.

## Linux

I don't have much experince with linux, but the way mentioned above should work. Just some small changes, you can try making a hidden directory in the HOME path like this

```py
from pathlib import Path
import os
change_dir_to = os.chdir(Path.home())
try:
    os.mkdir(".YourAppName")
except:
    pass
changed_dir_to = os.chdir(".YourAppName")
```

## MacOS

I don't have much experince with macos, but it should be like unix. So this should work, very similar to linux

```py
from pathlib import Path
import os
change_dir_to = os.chdir(Path.home())
try:
    os.mkdir(".YourAppName")
except:
    pass
changed_dir_to = os.chdir(".YourAppName")
```

## Check Modules on Startup

I don't recommend doing this as it will slow down the app, but if you wish, you can implement it as a different thread

Without Thread

```py
import subprocess
import pkg_resources

required = {'youtube-dl'}
installed = {pkg.key for pkg in pkg_resources.working_set}
missing = required - installed
if missing:
    python = sys.executable
    subprocess.check_call([python, '-m', 'pip', 'install', *missing], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
else:
    pass
```

With Thread

Check the documentation, ask me if you want, the answer is long already.

## Configuration

As for the Fireofx like configuration you asked, you should look in NSIS and learn the scripting language to create executables like setup.exe Alternatively, you can compile your components into a zip file and make a setup.exe which installs in a particular location from the inbuilt compiler.

### I hope that answered your question.

If you are interested in tkinter and python, check out my project [NoobNote](https://newtoallofthis123.github.io/NoobNote). I implement some of the features you want

> NoobScience

Comment: I would actually use a `try`/`except` block with `__import__` to check if the packages are installed. Also instead of `subprocess.check_call`, why not use `subprocess.Popen`?

Comment: The checking installed modules doesn't work for some libraries like `tensorflow` if you have installed `tensorflow-gpu`. Even though you use `tensorflow-gpu` the same way as the normal `tensorflow`.

Comment: Yes, You could do that.

Comment: As for the tensoroverflow, I don't think that is the case in this one. A simple requirements.txt would do

Comment: I am just showing you whysome people might find `try`/`except`/`__import__` more useful.

Comment: I understand that. But I think he wanted something to both check and if not not sucessful, install, but thanks.